# How can i compare 2 method in Java?

Tags: java, performance, methods, compare

I have 2 methods in java (for example Factorial calculation) and i have to test these 2 methods to find which one is faster. I have that code as Recursion and as for loop:

They both in the same Class data.

```
    public long FakultaetRekursiv( int n){
        if(n == 1){
        return 1;
        }
        else{
        return FakultaetRekursiv(n-1) * n;
        }
    }


    public long Fakultaet( int n){
        int x=1;
        for(int i=1; i<=n; i++){
            x= x*i;
        }
        return x;       
    }
```

I heard currentTimeMillis() could help a little but i dont know how to do exactly.
Thanks.

Comment: You should implement it by looking up the result in an array where all possible values are stored. That is quite sure the fastest implementation of *Fakultaet*.

Comment: Neither of these methods will run long enough to be optimised or to matter.

Comment: You should change your recursive implementation to check `n==0` instead of `n==1` because *0! == 1* by definition. And maybe throw an Exception for negative n values.

Answer (score 8):

[Micro-benchmarking is hard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/504103), use the right tools, for example [Caliper](http://code.google.com/p/caliper/). Here is an example that will work for you:

```
import com.google.caliper.SimpleBenchmark;

public class Benchmark extends SimpleBenchmark {

    @Param({"1", "10", "100"}) private int arg;

    public void timeFakultaet(int reps) {
        for (int i = 0; i < reps; ++i) {
            Fakultaet(arg);
        }
    }

    public void timeFakultaetRekursiv(int reps) {
        for (int i = 0; i < reps; ++i) {
            FakultaetRekursiv(arg);
        }
    }

}
```

The framework will run tour `time*()` methods a lot of times, moreover it will inject different `arg` values and bechmark them separately.

Comment: Make sure you do not ignore the result of the test-method. Once I had the case that my whole method seamed to be removed while optimization because the result was never used in the test loop.

Comment: @MrSmith42: +1. This problem is described in caliper documentation and caliper even tries to discover it. I wanted to keep the example short.

Comment: thank you so much for your comments guys. i learned a lot from you. But there is little thing that i supposed to use currentTimeMillis() to compare loop or recursive way works faster. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 3):

Always go by the basics ! Just use this to find the time taken by each of the functions

```
long startTime = System.nanoTime();
methodToTime();
long endTime = System.nanoTime();

long duration = endTime - startTime;
```

Comment: if i try to modify that with my code, i get a "unreachable statement" compiler mistake. how can i modify ?

Answer (score 3):

```
long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
```

// your code here

```
System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() - start + "ms");
```

Comment: well, when i want modify my codes with your solution. i reach a compile mistake(unreachable statement). so i made another class `public long getLastRuntime(){
   long start = System.currentTimeMillis();  
  return start;
  } 
`    and i changed my new code so `public long FakultaetRekursiv( int n){
   if(n == 1){
        return 1;
   }
      else{
        return FakultaetRekursiv(n-1) * n;
     }
   System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() - getLastRuntime() + "ms");

  }`

Comment: @altank52 maybe you are paste after `return` statement. Pls, show your code

Comment: @altank52 paste `System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() - getLastRuntime() + "ms");` before `return`

Comment: In here it wont look nicely but sure :`public class Rekursion{
    
  public long getLastRuntime(){
   long start = System.currentTimeMillis();  
  return start;
  } 
  public long Fakultaet( int n){
   int x=1;
   for(int i=1; i<=n; i++){
    x= x*i;
   }
   return x;  
  }
  
            public long FakultaetRekursiv( int n){
   if(n == 1){
        return 1;
   }
      else{
        return FakultaetRekursiv(n-1) * n;
     }
   System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() - getLastRuntime() + "ms");

  }
}`

Comment: when i paste that before the return statement, i get 0 ms back for whole loop :(

Comment: @altank52 try this: 
`long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
//invoke FakultaetRekursiv here 
System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() - start + "ms");`

Comment: we are working now on the Classes not on the demo program. i am sure your advices works on normal Main program(i tried and its work). But in class program that contains methods, i always have problem.

Comment: @altank52 Do this invoke(start finish) outside of recursion method

Answer (score -1):

You can also do it by hand:

The first method can be described with a recurrence relation of `F(x) = F(x-1) * x` which generates the pattern...

```
F(x) = F(x-1) * x
= F(x-2)*x*(x-1)
= F(x-3)*x*(x-1)*(x-2)
. . .
= k*n
```

which is O(n).

Obviously, the second method can be described by O(n) as well, which means they are in the same upper bound. But this can be used as a quick check before implementing timing solutions.

Comment: @MrSmith42 EDIT: You're right! - and I did mess up my big O notation.